Extended font size options not being applied on macos
I am running the following on macOS with macTex installed that does automatically install the extsizes package (verified as follows):
 sudo tlmgr install extsizes
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package already present: extsizes

$ pandoc leetcode.md -o leetcode.pdf -V fontsize=9pt

[WARNING] [makePDF] LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [9pt].

So I am at a loss on how to access the full range of font sizes. What is missing here?
Update  I do not have any TeX header in the file.  If I try to add one there is a "disagreement" between pandoc and the supplied
options:
Added header:
---
title: My Document
author: Someone
date: 30 Sep 2024
header-includes: |
    \documentclass[9pt]{extbook}
---

Results:
$ pandoc leetcode.md -o leetcode.pdf
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.81 \documentclass[9pt]{


Can you show a MWE of your .md file? Does it actually use any of the extsize classes or the package?

to expand, you need e.g. \documentclass[...]{extarticle} or extbook or whatever rather than just \documentclass[...]{article}. if you are loading the package, \usepackage{extsizes}, then you would get that warning if you gave 9pt as a class option, even though extsizes would pick up the size in that case. that's not the preferred way to use the package, but it should work. if you try it with just hello, world! in your document, you can easily check the document properties or use pdffonts to show what's used.

@cfr  The question was updated with details about attempting to add documentclass commands to the header (conflicts with pandoc defaults apparently)

you either need to change what pandoc uses class-wise or go with the package instead. I don't know what the downsides of the latter are - only that the classes are apparently preferable.

@cfr That worked! would you like to make it an answer?  I'll post the working code up in my question first and you can "lift" it for the answer

hmm ... so I filched your code as requested. can you remove it from the question as we're not meant to have answers in questions :-). or you could post another answer and I'll delete mine. (you'd have to unaccept mine for me to delete it, though.)

@cfr  Oh sure, i'm not going to nuke your answer, no way, removing here..

You either have to

alter pandoc so it loads e.g. extarticle rather than article - because you can't have two document classes; or
load the extsizes package instead.

The first is apparently preferred, but I don't know what the pros or cons of the second are. So, if the first is a problem, try adding \usepackage{extsizes} to the pandoc header1. Apparently (with the OP's permission), this should look like
---
title: My Document
author: Someone
date: 30 Sep 2024
header-includes: |
    \usepackage{extsizes}
---

and the OP also added the font size on the command line,
pandoc leetcode.md -o leetcode.pdf -V fontsize=8pt

1I assume this is what pandoc uses for the preamble of the document and not necessarily about the 'header' as LaTeX knows it.
